Flutter Google Sign-In: "ApiException: 10" Error Occurs on Windows (Works on MacOS)
I'm implementing Google Sign-In in my Flutter app, and I'm encountering an issue that I need help with.
Problem Description:
On MacOS:
When my colleague builds and runs the app on their MacOS computer, Google Sign-In works flawlessly.
Running the app on a physical device connected to the Mac also works without any issues.
On Windows 11:
When I build and run the same app on my Windows 11 computer, Google Sign-In fails with the following error:
PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)

What I've Tried:
Added SHA-1 Certificate Fingerprint:
Used keytool to obtain the SHA-1 fingerprint from my Windows computer's debug keystore:
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android

Added this SHA-1 fingerprint to the Firebase Console.
Attempted using all SHA-1 keys from the Google Play Console as well.
Verified OAuth Client ID:
Confirmed that the OAuth client ID in the Google Cloud Console matches the project.
Checked Package Name:
Ensured that the app's package name exactly matches the one registered in Firebase.
Granted Internet Permission:
Added internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Dependencies and Gradle Configuration:
pubspec.yaml dependencies:
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  google_sign_in: ^6.2.1
  firebase_auth: ^5.2.0
  firebase_core: ^3.4.0

android/build.gradle settings:
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2' // Added Google services classpath
    }
}


Applied the Google services plugin in android/app/build.gradle:
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
Updated SDKs and Plugins:
Ran flutter clean and rebuilt the project.
Updated all dependencies to their latest versions.
Environment Details:
Flutter Version:
Flutter 3.24.0-1.0.pre.490 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision d595e98d85 (8 weeks ago) • 2024-08-07 18:45:53 +0200
Engine • revision 5a0fd5fbec
Tools • Dart 3.6.0 (build 3.6.0-122.0.dev) • DevTools 2.38.0

Java Version:
java version "17.0.12" 2024-07-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.12+8-LTS-286)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.12+8-LTS-286, mixed mode, sharing)


Gradle Version:
Build time:    2024-08-14 11:07:45 UTC
Revision:      fef2edbed8af1022cefaf44d4c0514c5f89d7b78

Kotlin:        1.9.24
Groovy:        3.0.22
Ant:           Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.14 compiled on August 16 2023
Launcher JVM:  17.0.12 (Oracle Corporation 17.0.12+8-LTS-286)
Daemon JVM:    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17 (no JDK specified, using current Java home)
OS:            Windows 11 10.0 amd64

Additional Information:
Difference in Development Environments:
MacOS Developer's Computer:
Google Sign-In works when the app is built and run on MacOS.
Tested on a physical device; everything functions correctly.
My Windows 11 Computer:
Using the same source code, Google Sign-In fails with ApiException: 10.
The issue occurs on both emulator and physical device.
Other Attempts:
Ensured that Google Play Services are up to date on the testing devices.
Cleared cache and rebuilt the project using flutter clean.
Verified that all plugins and dependencies are up to date.
Question:
What could be causing the ApiException: 10 error only when building on Windows?
Are there any additional configurations or settings specific to Windows that I need to check?
Could this issue be related to the debug keystore differences between MacOS and Windows? If so, how can I resolve it?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Added SHA-1 Certificate Fingerprint:
Used keytool to obtain the SHA-1 fingerprint from my Windows computer's debug keystore:
bash
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "%USERPROFILE%.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
Added this SHA-1 fingerprint to the Firebase Console.
Attempted using all SHA-1 keys from the Google Play Console as well.
Verified OAuth Client ID:
Confirmed that the OAuth client ID in the Google Cloud Console matches the project.
Checked Package Name:
Ensured that the app's package name exactly matches the one registered in Firebase.
Granted Internet Permission:
Added internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml:

Windows is not supported:

Android, iOS, MacOS, Web.
More info: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/103682
